# Present formsheet modal ViewController using horizontal flip

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I currently show a modal UIViewController in the formSheet style that was presented with the coverVertical animation. I am trying to present another modal UIViewController from it, using currentContext for the presentation style and flipHorizontal for the animation style. It does work, but there is a solid white white background behind the flip as it occurs. Any advice on how to successfully present another formsheet modal UIViewController using the flipHorizontal style from a pre-existing modal UIViewController in the formSheet style would be appreciated please! Thanks

Code:

```
// Loading of first modalVC
- (void)showModalVC {

    Modal1VC *modal1VC = [[Modal1VC alloc] init];
    modal1VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    modal1VC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:modal1VC animated:YES];
    [modal1VC release];

    modal1VC.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400);
}

// Loading of second modalVC in Modal1VC
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *modal2VC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    modal2VC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    modal2VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    modal2VC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self presentModalViewController:modal2VC animated:YES];
    [modal2VC release];

    modal2VC.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400);
}
```

Comment: Post your current version of code...

Comment: Same issue here! But @superjessi is right that the white is the Window color. If I set to clearColor, it becomes BLACK :(

Answer (score 4):

```
UIViewController *presentingViewController = //allocate your VC
[modalViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
UIViewController *modalViewController = //your modal VC
[presentingViewController presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

This is all the code you need ;)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your transition is working, but the white background shown on the flip transition is the problem?

During the flip transition, the white background that is shown is actually the `window`.  You can change the color that is shown by setting the `backgroundColor` property of `window` in the `AppDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

That would seem to be a limitation of `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

Instead of `[self presentModalViewController:modal2VC animated:YES]`, you may be able to get the effect you want using UIView animations. Perhaps something like this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                  duration:0.3
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                animations:^{
    [self presentModalViewController:modal2VC animated:NO];
} completion:NULL];
```